# Misunderstanding about asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ be IID $X \sim \mathrm{unif}[0,\theta]$, for $\theta > 0$.

I am looking to find the asymptotic distribution of $\max\{X_{i}\}=X_{(n)}$ through the following equation:

$$P \left( n(\theta - X_{(n)}) \leq x \right) = P \left(X_{(n)} \geq \theta - \frac{x}{n} \right) = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta - (x/n)}{\theta}\right)^{n} \to 1 - e^{-x/\theta}$$

as $n \to \infty$.

I would like to conclude that the asymptotic distribution of $X_{(n)}$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\theta^{-1}$, but I don't see how to conclude this. I can see that this is true for $n(\theta - X_{(n)})$. What can we conclude about the asymptotic distribution of $X_{(n)}$? It seems as if its asymptotic distribution function is $e^{-x/\theta}$, which is a decreasing function (so not sure how that makes sense).

**EDIT:** I realize I was working with the wrong definition of asymptotic distributions, so this question isn't very meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asymptotic distribution of $X_{(n)}$ isn't exponential, which is why you can't show it.  Step back and think about it for a minute.  If your sample size is, say, $n = 10^6$ iid observations drawn from a $\operatorname{Uniform}[0,\theta]$ distribution, isn't $X_{(n)}$ *almost certainly* going to be very, very close to $\theta$?  As $n \to \infty$, $X_{(n)}$ converges in probability to $\theta$.

Indeed, the fact that the asymptotic distribution of $n(\theta - X_{(n)})$ is non-degenerate should also suggest that $X_{(n)}$ itself cannot be exponentially distributed, since, informally, as $n \to \infty$, we would need $\theta - X_{(n)} \to 0$.